# How to handle a specific user error in the input fields using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am doing a website for my scraper. On that website I have three input fields (the second one is optional). If the user does not enter anything in the first or third field a message like this shows up:

[image]

After you have entered the city name but not the last field the same message will appear on the last field.

I want to handle so that the user cannot enter anything in the last field expect "wohnung" or "haus". I have written a code for it but it is not working. If a user enters anything in the field it shows that scraping has started, as shown in the next picture:

[image]

So if the user enters anything expect the above mentioned words I want it to show up like if they wrote nothing.

Function for handling input fields is the following:

```
def run_scraper(city, subregion, apart_or_house):
    # Ask the user for input
    base_url = ""
    while True:
        if city != "":
            break
        else:
            flash("City name cannot be empty. Please enter a valid city name.", "error")
            return

    while True:
        if apart_or_house == "wohnung" or apart_or_house == 'haus':
            break
        elif apart_or_house == "":
            flash("This field cannot be empty. Please enter what are you buying.", "error")
        else:
            flash("Please enter either 'wohnung' or 'haus'.", "error")
            return

    if subregion:
        base_url = f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/{city}/{city}/{subregion}/{apart_or_house}-kaufen"
    else:
        base_url = f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/{city}/{city}/{apart_or_house}-kaufen"

    #Run the scraper script with the provided inputs and base_url
    subprocess.run(['python', 'scraper.py', city, subregion, apart_or_house, base_url])
    session['scraping_finished'] = True
    flash('Scraper has finished!', 'info')
    g.scraping_finished = True
```

and the code of the route where it is called is the following:

```
@app.route('/scrape', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def scrape():
    form = ScrapingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        city = request.form.get('city')
        subregion = request.form.get('subregion')
        apart_or_house = request.form.get('apart_or_house')

        if city and apart_or_house:
            g.scraping_finished = False
            threading.Thread(target=run_scraper, args=(city, subregion, apart_or_house)).start()
            flash('Scraping started!', 'success')
        else:
            flash('Please fill all required fields.', 'error')

    if g.get('scraping_finished', False):
        flash('Scraper has finished!', 'info')

    return render_template('scrape.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Your code first flashes "Please enter either 'wohnung' or 'haus'.", "error", then the function returns and the next flash pops up flash('Scraping started!', 'success')

Comment: I want it to flash('Scraping started!', 'success') once everything is entered correctly.

Comment: But why does it flash the message when the input field is empty and does not flash("Please enter either 'wohnung' or 'haus'.", "error")_

Comment: You can put flash('Scraping started!', 'success') after checking the inputs in your run_scraper

Comment: Okey, but the question still remains why the code does not flash the following: flash("Please enter either 'wohnung' or 'haus'.", "error")?

Comment: Did you try it and still didn't show that error?

Comment: The issue that I am trying to solve is to limit the user for entering anything expect "wohnung" or "haus" in the third field. If the enters anything else it should flash a message like it flashes when the field is empty.

Comment: Ok. I said that move that flash('Scraping started!', 'success') from scrape() to run_scraper and place it after the second while. The problem should be solved. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to limit your choice between an apartment or a house, you can use your form. This eliminates the need for subsequent validation.

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Optional
from wtforms.widgets import CheckboxInput

class ScrapingForm(FlaskForm):
    city = StringField('City', 
        validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    subregion = StringField('Subregion', 
        validators=[Optional()]
    )
    apart_or_house = SelectField('Buying', 
        choices=[('wohnung', 'Apartment'), ('haus', 'House')], 
    )
```

```py
@app.route('/scrape', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def scrape():
    form = ScrapingForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        city = form.city.data
        subregion = form.subregion.data 
        apart_or_house = form.apart_or_house.data
        threading.Thread(target=run_scraper, args=(city, subregion, apart_or_house)).start()
        # ...
    return render_template('scrape.html', **locals())
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div>
            {{ form.city.label() }}
            {{ form.city() }}
            {% if form.city.errors -%}
                <ul>
                    {% for error in form.city.errors -%}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor -%}
                </ul>
            {% endif -%}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.subregion.label() }}
            {{ form.subregion() }}
            {% if form.subregion.errors -%}
                <ul>
                    {% for error in form.subregion.errors -%}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor -%}
                </ul>
            {% endif -%}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.apart_or_house.label() }}
            {{ form.apart_or_house() }}
            {% if form.apart_or_house.errors -%}
                <ul>
                    {% for error in form.apart_or_house.errors -%}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor -%}
                </ul>
            {% endif -%}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```